# Adding slope coefficient to plots with regression lines created using "pairs()" function

Tags: r, plot, coefficients

Is it possible to find and add slope coefficient values of the regression lines to the upper frames of this plot, instead of correlation coefficients? Thanks in advance.

```
reg <- function(x, y, col) abline(lm(y~x), col=col) 

panel.lm =  function (x, y, col = par("col"), bg = NA, pch = par("pch"), 
                      cex = 1, col.smooth = "red", span = 2/3, iter = 3, ...)  {
  points(x, y, pch = pch, col = col, bg = bg, cex = cex)
  ok <- is.finite(x) & is.finite(y)
  if (any(ok)) reg(x[ok], y[ok], col.smooth)}

pairs(iris[1:4], panel = panel.lm, upper.panel=panel.cor)
```

[image]

Comment: Yepp, just adjust the `panel.cor` function to include the intercept/slope in the `txt` variable, i.e. by using `paste` or `sprintf`. By now you've probably seen the examples in `?pairs`.

Comment: Thank you @RomanLuštrik. I'm having a bit of trouble adapting it, are you able to specifically show how to adjust panel.cor as you described? Thanks heaps!

Comment: Oh @RomanLuštrik I think my issue description may have been a little unclear... as well as adding the slope text, I need to actually find out what the slope of the regression line is in the first place, which I'm unsure how to do (just edited my original Q). Do you know how to find the slope of the regression line in my Q? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a little modified `coef.cor` from the help file of `?pairs`. Feel free to make it prettier.

```r
panel.coef <- function(x, y, digits = 2, prefix = "", cex.cor, ...) {
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))

  mdl <- lm(y ~ x)
  txt <- coef(mdl)[2]
  txt <- round(txt, 2)
  
  if(missing(cex.cor)) cex.cor <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
  text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex.cor)
}

pairs(iris[1:4], panel = panel.lm, upper.panel=panel.coef)
```

[image]